# Crystal Reports "Subreport bookmarks in main report"

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I have a Crystal Report (version 11.5) that uses bookmarks.  When the report is exported to pdf, it creates a bookmark for each branch of the "group by" clause.  This is implemented by checking a check box in "File->Export->Report Export Options".

I have a sub report that I insert into the main report.  It has a different "group by" pattern than the main report.  I want the bookmarks from the sub report to also show up in the main report.

Is there any way to do this?  What I'm trying to accomplish is different levels of bookmarks in the output pdf.  For example, my main "group by" has 5 fields so I get 5 levels of bookmarks.  In some cases, I only want 2 levels of bookmarks so that is why I pulled this out of the main report and into a subreport hoping I can get bookmarks with different levels.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best situation I found merges two pdf files.  Each will have a different grouping.  This is not ideal, but it works.